# change cell value based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
username     status      debt
 John        pending     $1000
 Mike        pending     $0
 Daymond     cleared     $0
```

How can I change the status of pending to cleared if the status is pending and debt is 0?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
m = df['status'].eq('pending') & df['debt'].eq('$0')

df.loc[m, 'status'] = 'cleared'
# or
df['status'] = df['status'].mask(m, 'cleared')
# or
df['status'] = np.where(m, 'cleared', df['status'])
```

```
print(df)

  username   status   debt
0     John  pending  $1000
1     Mike  cleared     $0
2  Daymond  cleared     $0
```